# Replacing URL structure and passing through content MOD_REWRITE & Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have Mod_rewrite on Apache display alternative content as per the following rules:-

- Queried url:- http ://www.example.com/page/
- Fetched url from server :- http:// www.example.com/tag-portfolio/

Without redirecting the browser - I.e. The user remains on the URL http ://www.example.com/page/

I have tried the following code below and also tried the codes [R,L] and [R=301,L] but to no avail. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this please?

Thanks in advance.

```
# BEGIN Rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^goose/?$ /tag-portfolio/$1 [P,L]
# END Rewrite
```

Comment: You rule looks like it should work. what is your problem?

Comment: @starkeen It might be that mod_rewrite is not enabled. Should it show up in php_info()? I'm on a VPS so anyway to enabled mod_rewrite in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# BEGIN Rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page(/?|/.+)$ /tag-portfolio$1 [NC,L]
# END Rewrite
```